# Drush output comes with color in a directory root while it comes without color in another

Tags: drush

I have set up two drupal virtualhosts in a VPS server under two different users. I had installed these at two different times so am not too sure about the specific install steps for Drush that I used. However what I see is that inside one of the drupal folders, drush commands come out with color output while the other comes without color.

That looked like a config file issue. I then tried to see how I was setting $PATH for the two.

In the one where Drush colors were coming up fine, the local vendor folder inside the drupal folder was included (actually the one outside - I am using the drupal scaffolding with composer based installs) in $PATH.

In the one where Drush colors were not coming up, the global vendor folder in the users home was included in the path.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

In the one where Drush colors were coming up, the vendor folder in the Drupal folder was included in the path.

```
export PATH="$HOME/www/domain/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

drush status showed that drush command was being run from the vendor folder in the drupal installation in both cases.

I have seen this in the past but thought I should get to the bottom of this, this time.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What does `drush --version` return you in each environment?

Comment: Yes, the no color drush is probably an older version. Installing drush in a global vendor dir is no longer supported anyway, so I would remove this drush install.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Both drush versions are 9.7.1. Also I see that the one where the colors are not working drush config loads an extra file /home/user/.drush/drush.yml in addition to the home/user/www/domain/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml and home/user/vendor/drush/drush.yml files

Comment: Ok. I removed the global drush install in the user that had the problem by editing the composer.json inside .config/composer and running composer update. I then updated .bashrc to only have the vendor bin folder inside the drupal root folder. Even then colors seem to not appear. I saw that ~/.drush had more config files for that user and that the one where colors were working ~/.drush had only a cache folder. So I deleted ~/.drush. Even then colors are not coming for drush output for that user.

Comment: I did the following 
diff /working-path/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml /not-working-ath/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
diff /working-path/drush/drush.yml /not-working-path/drush/drush.yml
diff /working-path/vendor/drush/drush/drush /not-working-path/vendor/drush/drush/drush - All files came out without any difference. So it is some other setting that is loaded that is causing the issue. Not from the yml files shown in drush status.

Comment: Dug into this again. I see that the console is colored based on the output of hasColorSupport inside Symfony/Ouput/StreamOutput. It just checks for @stream_isatty($this->stream); I did a echo of this value and I see that this function gets called thrice. In the site where this is working it print three 1s and where it is not working it prints 11<blank>.